# nginx proxy_pass not working in a expected way

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have front proxy as apache and back proxy as nginx. back proxy config is like below

```
location /my-app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:18080/my-app/;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
}
```

The problem is whenever the request sent to upstream from back proxy then double slash added

> to upstream --> /my-app//myappPath

I have tried to add slash at the end of location like below to avoid double slash but back proxy not receive any request from my front proxy. so no requests to upstream application.
Please kindly help me how to avoid this double slash situation in my back proxy.

```
location /my-app/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:18080/my-app/;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this directive:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:18080/my-app/
```

Remove the `"/"` at the end to:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:18080/my-app
```

That will take care of the issue.